# Trying to access the powerpoint and add text in the slide using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ms-office, powerpoint

Can anyone please send me the code,how to add the text in the existing power point using vbscript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check for some pointers in these articles:

[How to automate PowerPoint by using Visual Basic - Microsoft Support Microsoft Kb kb/555191](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222929)

[Automating a Powerpoint Presentation using VBA](http://www.mahipalreddy.com/vba/ppvba.htm)

The basics of the code are like this:

```
Dim oPPt, oPPs
Set oPPt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
oPPt.Visible = True
' Assuming your adding it to an existing powerpoint : '
Dim sPPtFile: sPPtFile = "C:\yourPowerpoint.pptx"
Set oPPs = oPPt.Presentations.Open(sPPtFile)

Dim oSlide
Set oSlide = oPPs.Slides.Add(1, 2)
oSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "My first slide "

oPPTFile.SaveAs "C:\yourPowerpointUpdated.pptx" 
oPPt.quit
set oPPt = nothing
```